# How do I convert a php date_diff value to a javascript integer?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to use the difference between two dates to help me draw lines on an `HTML` `canvas`.  I generate one date in `PHP` and extract the other which is stored in an `SQL` database

When I keep everything in `PHP` the echo'd output is exactly what I expect.  However, when I `json_encode` the output, which I expect to be an integer, to use to draw the shape I want on the `canvas`, a completely different number is presented from `javascript`.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the `json` encoding ... but I haven't been able to find any reference about how to do this properly.

Here's the `PHP` I use to grab, format, and create a date difference output:

```
$sdt = new DateTime($row['sdate']);
$today = new DateTime('now');

$sdiff = date_diff($sdt, $today);
$sdelta = $sdiff->format("%a");
```

If I keep all of this in `PHP` and either `echo` the variable or `echo` the `json_encode` variable I get the expected answer, which is 34.

```
echo $sdelta;
```

results in 34

```
echo json_encode($sdelta);
```

results in "34";

```
echo json_decode($sdelta);
```

results in 34;

However when I assign this value to a `javascript` variable and test the result of the assignment:

```
var diffdt = <?php echo json_encode($sdelta); ?>;
alert(diffdt);
```

The `alert` popup shows 199.

If anybody could help me with this issue, I'd be eternally grateful.

---

Extra information...

- Column type for `sdate` is `DATE`
- query I'm executing is to get the data is:

  ```php
  $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM register WHERE id = ? "); 
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); 
  $stmt->execute(); 
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  $num = $result->num_rows;
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  var_dump($row['sdate']);
  ```
- Number of rows is 1.
- vardump result is: string(10) "2019-09-27"

Comment: What does the rendered HTML page source look like? Ie, use your browser's _"View page source"_ option and see what's been inserted at `var diffdt = ...`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem ~ https://3v4l.org/RAM1B. If I copy that output directly into my browser console, it alerts the expected value.

Comment: Your example uses a date that isn't pulled from SQL, which I know you can't do in a demo for this page.  When I do this "static" method I can get the correct result.  However, when I pull the date from the SQL server, PHP displays the result properly but Javascript does not ... I'm pretty sure it is a formatting issue, but I have yet to figure out what I need to do to the format to have it produce the correct result.  I've tried using the PHP intval() function to no effect.

Comment: Have you checked the rendered HTML / JS source code yet? What **exactly** is the `sdate` value in your database?

Comment: What's REALLY killing me is that I am running a separate php file trying to debug this and it is giving me the correct answer.  When I copy that exact code over, something weird happens.  So now I have to figure out what this "something weird is".

Comment: Then all that stuff in your question about it showing "34" is untrue. It's time to knuckle down and do some actual debugging. What data-type is your `sdate` column (ie `VARCHAR`, `DATE`, `DATETIME`, etc)? What query are you executing to fetch the data? How many rows are returned? Find out **exactly** what value is in `$row['sdate']`, even if you just have `var_dump($row); exit;` you will see the values somewhere

Comment: Phil, I appreciate you asking these questions.  I have been looking at every piece of this problem from the database format to how each function I use in php and javascript actually operate (to make sure I haven't overlooked a parameter somewhere).  The fact that it works fine in one php file and not another is the only common piece of this ... I've been going through my code with a fine toothed comb trying to find my facepalm moment.  So everything I've stated so far is 100% true.

Comment: I am honestly just trying to help you here and it's almost 100% guaranteed to be a super simple mistake but it's very tedious to ask a bunch of questions and get only some or none answered. Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58636336/edit) and provide information on all the questions (there are **three**) and debugging suggestions (the `var_dump` example) in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636336/how-do-i-convert-a-php-date-diff-value-to-a-javascript-integer?noredirect=1#comment103670268_58636336)?

Comment: That `var_dump` appears to be a `DateTime` instance but I asked you for `var_dump($row)`. Please also make sure this is all coming from the problem file and not the one that _"works"_. And finally, please include this information by **editing your question**. The comments are not the right place.

Comment: Phil, var_dump($row) spits out everything in that row ... do you really want that all those values for each column?

Comment: It was more to verify that you actually did receive one row but I suppose it does not matter at this stage. What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201811/discussion-between-airider74-and-phil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up resolving this issue by moving php code outside some of the javascript I had written.  Problem was from a for loop I had implemented that updated javascript values from the php loop.  This was adding up the result.  None of my code actually changed, it was just rearranged.

Didn't think this was an issue since the for loop was doing it's job for what it was designed.

Thanks everyone for your help.  It allowed me to eliminate most of the other potential issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Must use "Number(your_number)" method** I used here,see bottom line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // To set two dates to two variables 
    var date1 = new Date("06/30/2019"); 
    var date2 = new Date("07/30/2019");

    // To calculate the time difference of two dates 
    var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    // To calculate the no. of days between two dates 
    var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24); 

    console.log(Number(Difference_In_Days));
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot see at all what this has to do with the question. Also, the explicit boxing via `Number` in your answer is redundant as the value is already a number

Comment: Need to pull the dates from SQL server ... If I just assign dates manually this issue doesn't occur ... Which is why I do the json encode

Comment: In JS, if a number is wrapped in quotes, it is interpreted as a String, and is tnerefore not a Number datatype.  You can test this with TypeOf(object);  If object = "34" this will return String, whereas if objecg = 34 this will return Number.  Number(object) forces JS to interpret the numbers in a String as a Number type.  i.e. Number("'34") will return 34 (a Number) and not "34" (a String).  It doesn't matter where the data comes from, but the format it is presented in will nudge the interpreter to consider it a particular datatype, unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: Phil, in the example, you are correct about the redundance-- however if applied to the problem it is correct and effective, for the reason stated above.  The cause is that the 'number' is presented in quotes, thereby designating a String.  Number(object) will return a Number object type that was stored in a String type.  The difference is a String is composed of a sequence character codes.  A number is not.

Comment: They are treated differently.  i.e. "3" + "4" returns "34";  3+4 returns 7.  String addition  concatenates multiple strings.  Number addition mathematically adds multiple Numbers.

Comment: @jdmayfield none of which happens in this question

Comment: What is actually being sent out from the php line?  If you had a test page with nothing but the php itself, no JS, what are the exact characters shown?

Comment: @jdmayfield here you go ~ https://3v4l.org/28GsP. If you have a read of all the comments above and the extended discussion, you'll see that whatever problem OP has, it has nothing to do with the code or data they've shown. I can say with 100% certainty though that this answer is not relevant at this time

Comment: var diffdt = "37";  alert(diffdt);  is what I get on the eval.  What browser/version are you getting this on?  Possibly it is the particular implementation of alert();  Definitely it should display the characters 37, whether a Number or a String.  Other than that I would say it's likely an encoding mismatch between the SQL data and the browser;

Comment: As stated by others, I cannot replicate without the specific SQL server.  What happens if you don't wrap your variable in the json_encode()?

Answer (score 0):

airider74 When you say that PHP shows the correct data but JS does not, what are you using to display the values-- i.e. console/terminal/browser etc.  ?  Are they both using UTF8?  Something you might try is encoding the output from the PHP via urlencode() and then decode it in JS via decodeURI() .

PHP:

```
echo urlencode(dIffdt);
```

JS:

```
var diffdt = "37";  alert( decodeURI(diffdt) );
```

Or try base64 encoding.

PHP:

```
echo base64_encode(diffdt);
```

JS:

```
var diffdt = "37";  alert( btoa(diffdt) );
```

I am thinking possibly your data is ASCII coming out of the server, but JS uses UTF8 by default (as do most modern browsers in a more general sense).